# R dataframe transpose feature

Tags: r, dataframe

please, I'm not an expert R programmer and I'm extremely confused about the below issue. I wonder if anybody could help me to understand.

```
tmp = head(mtcars,1)
tmp_tr = t(tmp)
tmp_tr_df = as.data.frame(t(tmp))

# let's now run the following:
cat("class tmp_tr -> ",class(tmp_tr)) # this is a matrix
cat("class tmp_tr_df -> ",class(tmp_tr_df)) # this is a dataframe

cat("\n rownames  'tmp_tr'  ->   (class:",class(rownames(tmp_tr)),")  -> ", rownames(tmp_tr))
# this gives: (class: character )  ->  mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
cat("\n rownames  'tmp_tr_df'  ->   (class:",class(rownames(tmp_tr_df)),")  -> ", rownames(tmp_tr_df))
# this gives: (class: character )  ->  mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb

cat("\n colnames  'tmp_tr'  ->   (class:",class(colnames(tmp_tr)),")  -> ", colnames(tmp_tr))
# this gives: (class: character )  ->  Mazda RX4
cat("\n colnames  'tmp_tr_df'  ->   (class:",class(colnames(tmp_tr_df)),")  -> ", colnames(tmp_tr_df))
# this gives: (class: character )  ->  Mazda RX4

# here is the problem:
cat("\n tmp_tr[1:3,] \n")
print(tmp_tr[1:3, ]) 
# this gives: 
# mpg  cyl disp 
#  21    6  160 

# however:
cat("\n tmp_tr_df[1:3,] \n")
print(tmp_tr_df[1:3, ])
# this gives: 
# [1]  21   6 160
```

what shall I do to make sure that the output of tmp_tr_df[1:3,]  is equal to the output given by tmp_tr[1:3,] ?
In other words, I need to work with dataframes, not matrices, however, if I work with tmp_tr_df it seems its behaviour is very weird.
Thanks

Comment: Base data frames (and matrices) "drop" dimensions by default when you use `[`. (But not when you use `t()`.)  You can disable this by using a `drop = FALSE` argument in `[`. `tmp[, 1]` is a vector, `tmp[, 1, drop = FALSE]` is a one-column data frame.

Comment: If you're just hoping to match that output format (of `tmp_tr[1:3, ]`) precisely, maybe something like this `print(setNames(tmp_tr_df[1:3, 1], rownames(tmp_tr_df)[1:3]))`?

Comment: You're not actually "working with data frames" however. `tmp_tr` is a matrix, `tmp_tr[1:3, ]` is a named vector, `tmp_tr[1:3, , drop = FALSE]` is a 3x1 matrix, `tmp_tr_df[1:3, ]` is an unnamed vector,  `tmp_tr_df[1:3, , drop = FALSE]` is a 3x1 data frame. So the result you're trying to duplicate is a named vector, and what you're getting is an unnamed vector.

Comment: The difference you're seeing is that when rows of a matrix within a single column are extracted to be a vector, the rownames are kept as names of the vector. For a data frame, the rownames are not kept as names of the vector. So Dunois's suggestion might be what you are looking for. But all of this seems a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - if you give us the context around this issue - what are you doing that this is what you need - we might be able to help you find a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you Gregor, I actually learned something new, much appreciated.